# Strange result with unitary transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, unitarity

If the unitary operation $\hat{U}$ turns the bases $|a\rangle$ to  $|b\rangle$ as $\hat{U}|a\rangle =|b\rangle$ then we have: $$\hat{U}=\sum_{aa'}|a'\rangle\langle a'|\hat{U}|a\rangle\langle a|=\sum_{bb'}|b'\rangle\langle b'|\hat{U}|b\rangle\langle b |$$ which results in $$\sum_{aa'}|a'\rangle\langle a'|b\rangle\langle a|=\sum_{bb'}|b'\rangle\langle a'|b\rangle\langle b|$$ or $$\sum_{aa'} \langle a'|b\rangle (|a'\rangle \langle a|-|b'\rangle \langle b|)=0.$$  This equation gives $|a\rangle =|b\rangle$ which seems kind of strange result! I would appreciate any help about this problem.

Comment: You are just mistaken. $\hat U\left|a\right>=\left|b\right>$ does not imply $\left<b^\prime\right|\hat U=\left<a^\prime\right|$

Comment: Thanks, but if we act $\hat{U} ^{\dagger}$ from both sides on $\hat{U}|a\rangle =|b\rangle$,  we have $U^{\dagger}|b\rangle =|a\rangle$ so $\langle b|U=\langle a|$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are correct. The mistake is somewhere else. Now, the identity operator is $\mathbb I=\sum_{a^\prime}\left|a^\prime\right>\!\!\left<a^\prime\right|$ so that your crazy equality is $\sum_a\left|b\right>\!\!\left<a\right|=\sum_{b^\prime}\left|b^\prime\right>\!\!\left<a^\prime\right|$; this is meaningless.

Comment: What happened when you tested your argument on an explicit two dimensional example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've stumbled on a pitfall of the bad habit which neglects to write down summation indices. $a$ or $b$ are not summation indices, but symbols distinguishing two different vector sets.

The relation $U|a\rangle =|b\rangle$ for all basis vectors $|a\rangle$ implies that $|b\rangle$ which you get after acting with $\hat{U}$ is still subject to summation like $|a\rangle$ is, even though $| b\rangle$ *looks* like a single vector due to a free index $b$ (which it is not).

When you express the sums with appropriate indices, all is clear. Assuming both sums of all projectors $\sum_{k'}|a_k'\rangle\langle a_k'|$ and $\sum_{k'}|b_k'\rangle\langle b_k'|$  give the unity operator (which is the case for orthonormal bases), we have

$$
\sum_{kk'} |a_{k'}\rangle \langle a_{k'} |\hat{U} |a_{k}\rangle \langle a_k | =  \sum_{kk'} |b_{k'}\rangle \langle b_{k'} |\hat{U} |b_{k}\rangle \langle b_k | 
$$
$$
\sum_{kk'} |a_{k'}\rangle \langle a_{k'} |b_{k}\rangle \langle a_k | =  \sum_{kk'} |b_{k'}\rangle \langle a_{k'} |b_{k}\rangle \langle b_k | 
$$

Subtracting the right-hand side, we get

$$
\sum_{kk'} \langle a_{k'} |b_{k}\rangle \bigg( |a_{k'}\rangle \langle a_k | - |b_{k'}\rangle \langle b_k | \bigg) = 0.
$$

One summation can be dropped since it acts as unity operator:

$$
\sum_k |b_{k}\rangle \langle a_k | - \sum_{k'} |b_{k'}\rangle \langle a_{k'} | = 0.
$$
Which is obviously correct - both terms are the same expression.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for responding late, but by your notation if we consider two-component bases, i.e., $k,k'=1,2$ we have: $$\langle a_1|b_1 \rangle (|a_1 \rangle \langle a_1|-|b_1 \rangle \langle b_1|) +     \langle a_1|b_2 \rangle (|a_1 \rangle \langle b_2|-|b_1 \rangle \langle a_2|) +      \langle a_2|b_1 \rangle (|a_2 \rangle \langle a_1|-|b_2 \rangle \langle b_1)+       \langle a_2|b_2 \rangle (|a_2 \rangle \langle a_2|-|b_2 \rangle \langle b_2|)=0$$ which again gives the previous strange results.

Comment: @H.Khani how it gives strange results? It no longer apparently implies $|a\rangle = |b\rangle$. I've edited my answer at the end.

Comment: Lalinsky, thanks for your great answer.